# Reading FormData from HttpContext in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

In Core 2.0, trying to read in my FormData posted from front end. I can manage to read the array of JSON objects, but not the `Files[]` array I'm also posting in the Form Data.

Here's the `Angular` component code which builds `FormData` :

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("MediaInfo",  JSON.stringify(minfo));
 
for(var i=0; i<this.importImages.length; i++){
    // append images to the files[] array
    formData.append("files[]", this.dataURItoBlob(this.importImages[i].TnUrl), this.importImages[i].name);
   }
```

And I call the following `Angular` service:

```js
 saveImportObjects(formData: FormData, params){
  let headers = new Headers();
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  options.params = params;

  var url = this.host + 'import/MediaUpload?' + this.getSessionID();

  return this.http.post(url, formData, options)
          .map((result: any) => {
            let res = result._body;
          })
          .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The Web Api code :

```js
[HttpPost]
[Route("MediaUpload")]
[DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MediaUploadAsync(string patientId, [FromQuery]string sessionId)
{

 FormOptions _defaultFormOptions = new FormOptions();

 if (!Helpers.MultipartRequestHelper.IsMultipartContentType(Request.ContentType))
 {
  throw new GetDataException("Unsupported Media Type");
 }

 var boundary = MultipartRequestHelper.GetBoundary(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(Request.ContentType), _defaultFormOptions.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit);            
 var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, HttpContext.Request.Body);
 var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
 
 StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(section.Body, Encoding.UTF8);
 var data = stream.ReadToEndAsync();

  List<MediaInfo> listMedia = new List<MediaInfo>();
 
 HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
 return msg;
}
```

The good news is that my `data` object is showing the array of objects (one object in this case); however, I'm not getting to my `Files[]` array:

```js
[{"PatientID":2,"PatientLastName":"Comprehensive","PatientFirstName":"Connie","DeviceID":"46","CSIInstanceID":9,"PatientDOB":"1958-09-09","FileName":"eye2.jpg","FileSize":5880,"ExamDate":"1/29/2018","PatientUID":2,"SessionID":"sessionID=4e92cdc3-3cba-4c96-86fa-d8049d9ea968"}]
```

Captured request in `Fiddler` tool:

```js
POST /api/import/MediaUpload?sessionID=cfe351c8-63f8-40b0-909d-d9a5991f6a70&patientID=11 HTTP/1.1

POST /api/import/MediaUpload?sessionID=cfe351c8-63f8-40b0-909d-d9a5991f6a70&patientID=11 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:49491
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 399616
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary62hryFjhCKbptVPz
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Same request via `Fiddler`, in the `TextView` of request:

```js
------WebKitFormBoundary62hryFjhCKbptVPz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MediaInfo"

[{"ID":11,"LastName":"Mazzo","FirstName":"Bob","DeviceID":"46","InstanceID":9,"PatientDOB":"1967-05-01","FileName":"Bob and Chris Cardillo.jpg","FileSize":399030,"ExamDate":"1/31/2018","UID":11,"SessionID":"sessionID=cfe351c8-63f8-40b0-909d-d9a5991f6a70"}]
------WebKitFormBoundary62hryFjhCKbptVPz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="Bob and Chris Cardillo.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Comment: You don't need to write your own file uploading code. Web API already allows you to upload files. Check [File uploads in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - thanks. In fact I saw that same post on Friday, but I wasn't sure if I could read in both my `Files[]` array as well as my `MediaInfo` array with this method. Or perhaps I should be using the `IFormFile` interface instead....

Comment: Not working for me. Even whenchanging the method signature to use `[FromBody]` : public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] List<IFormFile> files)` . The `files` param ends up being empty. I assume it's because I'm building my own `FormData` via my JavaScript above.

Comment: What's not working? What did you try? How are you sure the problem isn't in the Javascript code? Form data is form data. If the controller can't parse it, perhaps it's not correct. Start from a *form*, get multiple file uploads to work first. Use a tool like Fiddler to see what multi-file form POSTs look like, then replicate this in code

Comment: Use an `IFormFile` parameter and set the form encoding to `enctype='multipart/form-data'`, that should be enough to post your file through the form.

Comment: Could you post the actual JSON that you're sending over the wire? That will help answer if your payload is malformed in some way.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - agreed. FormData isn't complicated. I ended up finding a solution to read in both the files array, as well as the client info object. I posted it below, although I'm gonna have another crack at it with the link you've provided.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I added Fiddler request headers to my orig post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code working. I can now read in the `"MediaInfo"`object, as well as the `"files[]"` array.

```js
[HttpPost]
[Route("MediaUpload")]
[DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MediaUploadAsync(string Id, [FromQuery]string sessionId)
{
 AppSettings config = new AppSettings();
 var importConfig = config.GetImportConfig();
 var localPath = importConfig["ImportImageFolderPath"];

 FormOptions _defaultFormOptions = new FormOptions();
 List<MediaInfo> listMedia = new List<MediaInfo>(); 

 if (!Helpers.MultipartRequestHelper.IsMultipartContentType(Request.ContentType))
 {
  throw new GetDataException("Unsupported Media Type");
 }

 var boundary = MultipartRequestHelper.GetBoundary(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(Request.ContentType), _defaultFormOptions.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit);            
 var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, HttpContext.Request.Body);

 var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
 StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(section.Body, Encoding.UTF8);

 // READ FORM DATA
 if (section.ContentDisposition.Contains("MediaInfo"))
 {
  var data = stream.ReadLine();
  listMedia = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MediaInfo>>(data);                
 }
 
 CreateMediaOutput mediaOutput = new CreateMediaOutput(listMedia[0], localPath);
 
 // READ IMAGE FILES
 if (section.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
 {
  while ((section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync()) != null)
  {
   var file = section.AsFileSection().FileName;
   string fullPath = Path.Combine(localPath, file);
   FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fullPath);

   using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
   {
    await section.Body.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
   }
   mediaOutput.BusnLogicHere(fileInfo, sessionId); // internal busn logic..
  }
 }                        


 HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
 return msg;
}
```